# tabletop_segmentation fails (eigen error)

Tags: ros, eigen, tabletop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

using the customized object manipulation stack for sr_hand, with diamondback packages openni, household_object_database, tabletop_object_detector, object_manipulation, I ran into this error when asking to detect an object :

[ INFO] [1309279735.492363833]: Object detector: loading complete
[ INFO] [1309279735.499758174]: waitForService: Service [/tabletop_object_recognition] is now available.
[ INFO] [1309279735.504551066]: Tabletop complete node ready
[ INFO] [1309279881.128877336]: Tabletop detection service called; waiting for a point_cloud2 on topic /pcl_filters/fully_filtered
[ INFO] [1309279881.693557958]: Point cloud received; processing
[ INFO] [1309279881.696385938]: Input cloud converted to openni_camera frame
[ INFO] [1309279881.696465508]: Starting process on new cloud
[ INFO] [1309279881.696494434]: In frame openni_camera
[ INFO] [1309279881.698388688]: Step 1 done

**tabletop_segmentation: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ geometry/eigen/include/Eigen/ src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array< T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>( array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/ dox/UnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[ERROR] [1309279881.702883838]: Call to segmentation service failed

Not sure this is duplicate of ["eigen-package-error-while-running-tod_detecting"](http://answers.ros.org/question/981/eigen-package-error-while-running-tod_detecting)

What should I do to get rid of this error ?

best regards,
Guillaume WALCK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10436/tabletop_segmentation-fails-(eigen-error)/) by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
Because that package is for 64 bit system, so you should change some commands. Change them to this stype

pcl::PointCloud::ConstPtr table_projected_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud(table_projected));

---

Originally posted by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) with karma: 96 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on 2011-07-04**:
Indeed, I am running a 32bit Ubuntu. Thanks a lot, appears it was the reason it failed. I changed several such lines in tabletop_segmentation.cpp and I have no more issues. As soon as I get a 64bit version I will test again and come back if the changes are also required on 64bits.